# jQuery Mobile icons white instead black on Android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I'm having a problem with default jQuery Mobile icons. On Android device (any browser, checked on default Browser, FireFox and Chrome) the icons are white but should be black. On other devices (iPhone, Windows Phone, desktop computer) the icons are black as they should be.
I'm using latest stable jQuery Mobile 1.2.0. Let me know if anyone run to such problem.

Comment: Hi! Can you provide a screenshot and some code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had same problem.
I used Theme roller - http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller

There is probably small bug when CSS file is generated.
On line 789 is:

```
background-image: url(images/icons-36-white.png);
```

but should be:

```
background-image: url(images/icons-36-black.png);
```

Comment: I had the same problem as the author. This solution helped. I believe this should be a selected answer.

Comment: I also had the same thing, nice find!

Comment: Same issue. @Paul please mark as answer!! Just do a search in your custom .css files for "white" and change it to "black".

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I have not seen that problem before, but you can try to add class `ui-icon-alt` to the icons that you want to turn into black.

For all icons:

```
$('.ui-icon').addClass('ui-icon-alt');
```

Comment: Works, but only for some icons, icons for example in ListViews or in form elements are still white. Not too nice solution is to change all icon paths in all classes definitions to black.

Comment: If you prefer, change the `background-image` css property from `background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png);` to `background-image: url(images/icons-18-black.png);`.